# Appcelerator Installing app on device: Nexus 7

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Using Appcelerator when I tried to install app on 
Nexus 7, android 6.0.1 version

I get following error..

Installing app on device: Nexus 7
[ERROR] :  Failed to install apk on "xxxxx"

Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 0

What is the error and where? Install's fine in 4.0.x & 5.0.x

Thanks!

Comment: It's fine with my Nexus 7. It could be your device settings. Is USB Debugging turned on? Does it allow apps from unknown source?

Comment: Yes both is turned on in device settings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your time and suggestions.

What ultimately worked for me was going line by line in tiapp.xml file & removing or correcting the configurations in android manifest section..

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.0.1">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
        ****                       
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try to enable the USB Debugging mode and also try to plug-in/out USB cable and check whether the cable is not getting loose somehow while running on device.

If it not helps, please provide device details and screenshot of console output.

Answer (score 0):

While the device is connected disable debugging mode and then enable it. Then see if the device is detected by its name. If it is then try build and run the app. This trick worked for me.